# TWAIN and WIA of -Avision AV175+ Scanner- Stopped working on HP Thin Client

Tags: windows-7, 32-bit, scanner, windows-embedded-7, twain

We have th [HP t530 Thin Client](https://www8.hp.com/ie/en/products/thin-clients/product-detail.html?oid=27890212) (6KP61EA) running **Microsoft Windows 7 Embedded** 32bit.
We Have [**Avision AV175+**](https://www.avision.com/motion.asp?siteid=100407&lgid=4&menuid=10075&prodid=121331&cat=9) Scanner and we installed it successfully.
Suddenly 3 days ago it stopeed working with the **TWAIN** or **WIA** service.
Which means, that when we scan document, it pulls the paper but dont popup the following:

[image]

We try to install the driver again but without any luck.

We tested it- we installed a new Windows 7 Embed 32bit, and we noticed that when we install the AV175+ scanner locally (without any internet connection) it was "install" the driver (means, it display that it was installed), But, when checking on device manager we discover that the driver wasnt installed **AT ALL**.
It does pops up the **Microsoft Windows Driver Search** window that search for driver, But eventually without success:

[image]

We check if it was some Update we got lately but we discover that **no updates** was installed at all.

We preform and implement live image from **SAME** working system that came from another **SAME** T530 Thin Cliet- Where the scanner IS WORKING. But we got strange thing:
The scanner got the same issue!
How it can be??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this mess, we realized that after we tried to install the WIA on the 175+, it suddenly began to receive a WIA error in a standard scan.
When we installed only the TWAIN driver everything worked properly.
We removed the 175+ installation and install only the TWAIN driver, and now its fine.